# Octal Escape in Java result in wrong byte value, Encoding problem?

Tags: java, linux, encoding, utf-8

According to this documentation ( http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html , 3.10.6) an OctalEscape will be converted to an unicode character. Now I have the problem, that the following code will result in a 2 byte Unicode character with wrong informations.

```
for (byte b : "\222".getBytes()) {
     System.out.format("%02x ", b);
}
```

The result is "c2 92". I was expacting only "92", because this would be the converted value from 222 octal to hex (92).
If I test this with a character, the byte informations are correct.

```
System.out.format("%02x ", (byte)'\222');
```

The result is "92" for one byte"
My default encoding is "UTF-8" on Linux with Java/c 1.6.0_18.

The background of my question is, that I'm looking for a method to convert an octal escaped string from the input encoding Cp1252 to UTF-8. This fails because of the conversion of an octal escaped string to 2 bytes.
Does somebody know why there is always an extra byte "c2" been added to the char array? A simple count shows, that there is only one character in the array.

```
System.out.println("\222".toCharArray().length); // will result in "1"
```

Thank you for your hints.

Update:
As BalusC mentioned the octal escaped value is interpreted as UTF-8 value, which yield the problem. As long as this value is saved in the source code (UTF-8) I have no possibility to read in this string with an other encoding. I'm right? If I read an Cp1252 encoded file, I have to declare the charset of the InputReader with the correct charset and do an encoding to UTF-8 to process and save the read content as UTF-8.

Comment: What does it mean "convert an octal escaped string from the input encoding Cp1252 to UTF-8"? Show the example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: Your statement in the update is wrong. `\222` is treated as a Unicode codepoint `U+0092`, and it doesn't depend on the source encoding. Then `String.getBytes()` returns a representation of that codepoint in your default encoding. Since your default encoding is `UTF-8`, you get `c2 92`, that is a representation of `U+0092` in `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`String#getBytes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) call without a specified encoding will use the platform default encoding to convert characters to bytes. Since `c2` is a typical first byte of a two-byte character of the [multibyte UTF-8 sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), you're apparently using UTF-8 as platform default encoding. If you want to get CP1252 bytes, then you need to specify that explicitly in the [`String#getBytes(String charsetName)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
for (byte b : "\222".getBytes("cp1252")) {
     System.out.format("%02x ", b);
}
```

---

**Update** as per your update:

> As long as this value is saved in the source code (UTF-8) I have no possibility to read in this string with an other encoding. I'm right?

That's correct. You need to read the file using the same encoding as the file was saved in, otherwise you may risk to end up with [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

> If I read an Cp1252 encoded file, I have to declare the charset of the InputReader with the correct charset and do an encoding to UTF-8 to process and save the read content as UTF-8.

Just read the file as CP1252 using `InputStreamReader`. When read as characters (strings), Java will store it implicitly as Unicode (UTF-16). You can treat the data as Unicode. There's no need to introduce an intermediating UTF-8 file step. If you want to save the file, use `OutputStreamWriter` with the desired charset, this can be different from CP1252. Only keep in mind that any character which isn't covered by the charset will end up as `?`.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - how to get characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: This result in an output of "3f". Which is not the octal value, that I was given in.

Comment: It's the hexadecimal representation of the byte which is representing the **CP1252 character** as represented by the octal `\222`. `92` is the value when you convert the **literal string** `222` from octal to hexadecimal. I think that you need to revise the functional requirement after all. Maybe you're missing one conversion layer (the character encoding itself, I bet).

Comment: Little correction: `3f` is a `?`. It's printed because Unicode character `U+0092` can't be represented in CP1252.

Comment: @axtavt: Ah I didn't check for that. It was just from top of head. But indeed, the CP1252 doesn't support that character.

Answer (score 3):

All chars and strings in Java are UTF-16. So, you have entered the control character [U+0092 PRIVATE USE TWO](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) and encoded it to UTF-8 (this character takes two bytes when encoded as UTF-8). Characters encoded as anything other than UTF-16 must be represented by byte arrays.

## U+2019: ’

I'm guessing you intend to transcode the character [U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf). In windows-1252, this has a byte value of `92`. I hate to disappoint, but when encoded as UTF-8 this is going to end up as the multi-byte sequence `E2 80 99`.

*Also note that U+2019 can't be represented by octal escape sequences in Java as it has a value over U+00FF. You'd have to use the Unicode escape sequence `\u2019`. I wrote a blog post about transcoding in different languages [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/04/i18n-comparing-character-encoding-in-c.html) and encoding in Java source files [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_sourcefiles).*

Comment: Actually I read some of your blog posts and helped a lot understanding the IHMO complex topic of character encoding. It's like regex, voodoo in the beginning, but really powerful if you dig deeper. THX